# Search mail content in WLM (Windows Live Mail)

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-mail, windows-live

I can search the word in `mail subject` or `sender/receiver` of a mail easily as:

[image: Searching sender/subject in WLM]

But, I want to search `a word in mail content`.

I tried following:

[image: Search content]

But the "`Message`" option greyed out!

Why? How to search content?

Comment: Just FYI... I found the search capabilities of all mail-clients severely lacking. If you like a flexible search you might try a third party program like the free (for personal use) [MailStore Home](http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home.aspx).

Comment: @Rik Thanks for the suggestion and `MailStore Home` link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't search `mail content of ALL folders`.

You can search `mail content of only one folder at a time`.

Example:

You get the "`Message`" option greyed out, if you try searching in "`All inboxes`":

[image: Can't search in "<code>All inboxes</code>"]

You can search `individual inbox` as follows:

[image: Can search in an inbox]

Then click on this "`Message`" in "`Find`".

You will get following:

[image: Search content]